# How to send Amazon SES bounce notifcation emails to civiCRM bounce processing email address?

Tags: bounce, amazon-ses

I'm trying to follow the helpful guide here on setting up Amazon SES

https://www.compucorp.co.uk/node/1740

All working well apart from bounce handling.  Amazon SES by default seems to send bounce notifications back to the sending email address.

How to send from members@site.com and get bounce notifcations to bounce@site.com using Amazon SES?

Comment: See the docs at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#special-email-address-for-incoming-email and also the section on incoming mail. I'm not sure if you can send from one address from civi and have it bounce to another, except for the variations of the sender address used by VERP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out now.  I'd not understood that bounce processing works only with bulk emails and not with 'transactional' emails.  All works fine if you know this!

Comment: Hi @dgk12 - I am trying to get the bounce processing to work with SES as well. Could you please tell me what details did you put in the mail account settings in CiviCRM? Also was there any changes from the AWS SES side that had to be made? Thanks.

Comment: hi Sohal - sorry for slow reply.  did you figure this out now?!